# Use chflags to lock files but not folders?

Tags: command-line, monterey, macos

I want to recursively lock all the files within a hierarchy, using chflags; but I don't want to lock the folders themselves.

If it helps, the files all start with "DSC", but the folders don't.

Obviously, the complex method is to loop through each item, test it, and then run chflags on it, but I'm hoping there's a simpler way.

Comment: Just use `find` to identify each file. Something like- `find . -type f -name 'DSC*' -exec chflags <options> {} +`

Comment: Thanks. I was trying `find -df . DSC*` which wasn't working.

Comment: @benwiggy You'd have to use something more like `find . -name 'DSC*'`. The `-name` predicate to test for a filename match, and quotes to prevent the shell from prematurely expanding that wildcard. `-d` (depth-first search) is irrelevant here, and `-f` is only needed if you're specifying things in an unusual order.